# What is the most portable way to open the default Java truststore?

Tags: java, java-8, aws-lambda, keystore

I am programmatically manipulating the default Java TrustStore. In order to do that, I need its path.

I tried reading `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and they're both undefined.

I came up with `System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/jre/lib/security/cacerts"`, is it the right approach?

It works but I'd like the code to be as portable and future-proof as possible.

Edits:

1. This is for an app running in AWS Lambda, Lamda does not allow to customize or provide your own JRE.
2. This question was originally asking for the default keystore. I changed it to truststore since keystores are app-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You probably won’t have permission to modify files in an installed JRE.  And that path does not exist, starting with Java 9.

Furthermore, as of Java 11, there is no JRE.  The only way to distribute an application is to use [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html) to create an image containing a subset of Java SE containing only the modules required by the application.

In summary, you can’t rely on a Java installation, and even if you find one, you can’t rely on the presence of a default keystore file.

You shouldn’t be changing a user’s Java installation anyway.  Your code should include a custom keystore file as an application [resource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), which you should pass to [Keystore.load](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html#load%28java.io.InputStream,char[]%29):

```
InputStream embeddedKeystore =
    MyApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("custom-keystore.pkcs");

assert embeddedKeystore != null : "Application was not properly built."
    + " Keystore is missing!";

KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
keystore.load(embeddedKeystore,
    new char[] { 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 'f', 'i', 's', 'h' });

embeddedKeystore.close();
```

Comment: For context, this is run by AWS Lambda which does not allow to customize or provide your own JRE. I will add it to the question. Lambda allows me to change the keystore. Thanks for the info about Java 9 and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my solution so far.

In my question, I was reading from `System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/jre/lib/security/cacerts"` but that is the path of the JDK (which isn't installed on AWS Lambda) and is the root of the /jre folder.

```java
String trustStoreLocation = Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"))
    .orElseGet(() -> System.getProperty("java.home") + "/lib/security/cacerts");

File trustStoreFile = new File(trustStoreLocation);
if (!trustStoreFile.exists()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate the Java TrustStore: the system property javax.net.ssl.trustStore is undefined or " + trustStoreLocation + " does not exist.");
}

KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(trustStoreFile)) {
    keyStore.load(fis, new char[] { 't','h','e',' ','p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d' });
}
```

Comment: Is that groovy? I wasn't aware Java had an elvis operator (`?:`).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Thank you! I am using Kotlin, which compiles to Java bytecode. Since it's not a Kotlin-specific question I am asking as a Java issue and translating my code back to Java. I forgot about this part :) Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own path for the trustsotre and the keystore using passing system property option to the JVM

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=your_custom_path
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=your_custom_path
```

Comment: My JRE is run by AWS Lambda. I do not have control over the way it is started. Those system properties are undefined with AWS Lambda.

Comment: It looks like AWS Lambda  environment is very limited, still you can use JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable